# Get group members count using facebook api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Actually I can get a members list from an OPEN group on facebook using `GET /v2.4/{group-id} HTTP/1.1`. The problem is, that query return me not all the users on the group.

I.E, the group have 2020 members and graph api only returns me a list of size 1980. What happens with those 40 members?

There is a way I can get the exactly amount of members?, I been digging on the facebook API but I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get the exact amount, some users may have deactivated the App Platform. You can never be sure to get access to everyone, there is no reliable way to get the correct group members count.